# Jmeter test always freeze when tested server gives up

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, freeze

When trying to run load test in JMeter 5.1.1, tests always freeze at the end if server gives up. Test completes correctly if server does not give up. Now this is terrible because the point of test is to see at what point server gives up but as mentioned test never ends and it is necessary to kill it by hand.

Example:

- Test running 500 threads for local server goes smoothly and it finish
  with `tiding up` message
- Exactly the same test running 500 threads    for cloud based server
  at some points results in error test goes to    about 99 % then
  freezes on summary as in below example:

> summary +     99 in 00:10:11 =    8.7/s Avg:   872 Min:   235 Max: 
>   5265 Err:     23633 (100.00%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 480

and that's it you can wait forever and it will just be stuck at this point.

Tried to use different thread types without success. Next step was to change Sampler error behavior and yes changing it from `Continue` to `Start Next Thread Loop` or `Stop thread` helps and test is ending but then results in html look bizarre and inaccurate. I even tried to set timeout setting to 60000 ms in HTTP request Defaults but this also has given strange results.

That said can someone tell me how to successful run load test for server so that is always completes regardless of issues and is accurate> Also I did see few old question about the same issue and they did not have any answer that would be helpful. Or is there any other more reliable open source testing app that also has GUI to create tests?

Answer (score 1):

You're having 100% of errors which looks "strange" to me in any case.

If setting the connect and response timeouts in the HTTP Request Defaults doesn't help - most probably the reason for "hanging" lives somewhere else and the only way to determine it is taking a [thread dump](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html) and analyzing the state of the threads paying attention to the ones which are [`BLOCKED` and/or `WAITING`](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-analyze-thread-dumps-using-a-java-thread-dump-analyzer/). Then you should be able to trace this down to the JMeter Test Element which is causing the problem and closely look into what could go wrong.

Other hints include:

- look for suspicious entries in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file
- make sure JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network sockets, etc. It can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
- make sure to follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/)

Comment: I did check jmeter logs and there is nothing suspicious in there also test machine has enough cpu power and ram to run such test.